# extern "C" with class and DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, dll, extern

I was presented with a C++ DLL source code that uses `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C"
{
    class Something
    {
       public:
         __declspec(dllexport) Something();
         __declspec(dllexport) virtual ~Something();
         __declspec(dllexport) bool function_one(const char * some_text);
         static __declspec(dllexport) char * get_version();
       private:
          unsigned int m_data;
    };
}
```

The DLL is being called by a C++ program.
FYI, using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7 platform.

**Questions** *(all related to the `extern "C"` and `class`):

1. Since `class` is not C language, will this be equivalent to a
   `struct`?
2. Are constructors valid?
3. Are virtual destructors valid (since C doesn't have `virtual`)?
4. How is the `bool` handled?
5. How is `static` treated inside the `extern "C"` for the class?
6. How is `private` data handled inside the `extern "C"` block?
7. How is `noexcept` handled in an `extern "C"` block for the
   constructor?

The Visual Studio 2017 compiler is not generating any errors or warnings with the above code.

The VS2017 code analyzer only generates a warning for the constructor:

```
C26439 This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).
```

**Research:**
The questions on StackOverflow related to this issue mention that the "extern "C"`has the effect of resolving name mangling.  However, they don't address the issues of`virtual`,`bool`, private data, and etc. as I listed above.

Also, many DLLs related answers recommend not using non-POD structures because the layout may change between compilers (including same versions of compilers); so for example, character arrays are preferred over `std::string`.

Comment: `extern "C"` does not mean "compile this code as C code". It means "generate compiled code that can be called from C code". That's primarily about external names and calling conventions, and it's **strongly** about the interaction between the C compiler and the C++ compiler.

Comment: This source code smells. First, one can use `__declspec(dllexport)` on the class instead of individual members, which is painfully verbose. Second, declspec is nearly always hidden in a macro which expands to either export or import variant, depending on what is being compiled. Third, `extern "C"` doesn't make much sense for class members and is therefore ignored.

Comment: I'm confused.  The C language does not have the concept of a virtual destructor, so how would that be called from C code?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, much source code smell; which is why I posted here.  The source code given to me is confusing, such as having a `private` access specifier.

Comment: Member functions cannot be called from C code, which is the reason why `extern "C"` does not apply to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't change the code to be C. It causes no C++ name mangling to be done - so you cannot overload functions exposed as `extern "C"` inside that block, for example, but the code is still C++.

You are just restricted from doing stuff that would not be callable from C (in the `extern "C"` block). You are exposing a C API but you can still use C++ behind the scenes. Just not in your `extern "C"` *part of the interface*.

This also means that you cannot export member functions (`virtual` or not) as `extern "C"` because C has no such thing.

Comment: @Peter hopefully my edits made that a bit more clear.

Comment: My somewhat hyper-technical comment whenever this comes up is that `extern "C"` does not turn off name mangling; it specifies using the C compiler's name mangling, which usually prepends an underscore to a function name.

Comment: @Peter Ok, *I* tend to think of it simply as "cause this code to be calllable using C calling conventions (which includes doing whatever/no name mangling which will be compatible with C)". Anyway, I think we agree and are just nitpicking details that (at this point) don't do much to help OP - or?

Comment: That's why I said it's "hyper-technical".

Comment: Is the `virtual` concept ignored and the destructor consider a non-special function?

Comment: I have an overloaded function in the private section of the class, which would not be accessible from outside anyway and the compiler is giving me an error. Am I trying to do something illegal? (I composed my class exactly as the OP) Could you expand you answer to include this possibility as well?