# Creating shared c library with QT

Tags: c++, qt, go

I'm trying to create a shared(dynamic) c++ library with QT however in the client application which is going to use this library , there wont be any qt libraries linked.

I've followed the tutorials about qt and created a pro file and header file as in below example.

**Pro File:**

```
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += dynamiclib

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS, MAITSCHSDK_LIBRARY

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    maitchsdk.cpp

HEADERS += \
    maitchsdk.h

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**Header File:**

```
#ifndef MAITCHSDK_H
#define MAITCHSDK_H

#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#if defined(MAITSCHSDK_LIBRARY)
#  define MAITSCHSDK_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MAITSCHSDK_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class MAITSCHSDK_EXPORT  MAItchSDK
{
public:
    MAITSCHSDK_EXPORT MAItchSDK(const char *glimpseIp,int glimpsePort,const char *itchIp,int itchPort);
};

#endif // MAITCHSDK_H
```

But when I implement it like this, the header file contains qt dependencies so the client application also needs to have this dependencies which is not what we wanted.
And another requirement that I have is, this library can be called with golang too (by using cgo) so somehow I need to create a c wrapper for this library project with some **extern "C"** methods, I've looked through all the documents and tutorials but couldnt able to find a proper solution.

Does anyone have any idea about how can I create a basic C shared library with using QT ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> But when I implement it like this, the header file contains qt dependencies so the client application also needs to have this dependencies which is not what we wanted.

To remove the dependency on Qt, you must make sure your header does not `#include` any Qt headers.

In your case, you have `#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>` which is used for the cross-platform macros `Q_DECL_IMPORT`/`Q_DECL_EXPORT`. Remove those from your header and replace the cross-platform macros with your platform-specific version (e.g. `Q_DECL_IMPORT` -> `__declspec(dllimport)` for Windows)

> somehow I need to create a c wrapper for this library project with some **extern "C"** methods, I've looked through all the documents and tutorials but couldnt able to find a proper solution.

This is a completely separate problem from the one above.

Qt itself doesn't care if you use `extern "C"` in your code or not. So, focus on building your "normal C++" DLL without Qt dependencies first.

Once you've succeeded, you don't need to change your *.pro file anymore. Just wrap all of your exported functions in your header with `extern "C" { ... }`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-c-functions-for-use-in-c-or-cpp-language-executables?view=vs-2019 for a simple example.

Also, see this StackOverflow answer on the restrictions you must follow when using `extern "C"`: [extern "C" with class and DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261768/extern-c-with-class-and-dll)